# Eu quero retornar as palavras exatamente iguais mas não sei como fazer isso

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho um problema que quando tento retornar as palavras que pretende ele também retorna as palavras que têm uma virgula ou qualquer caracter.

Por exemplo,

"Eu tenho esta frase que serve, para serve e que serve[1] de serve."

E quando tento imprimir ele retorna

`{'serve':(4,1)}` e queria que retornasse `{'serve':(1,1)}` porque não quero as palavras com , e [1] e .

Eu tenho estas quatro funções:

- a função analisarPalavras serve para contar quantas vezes a palavra aparece num .txt
- a função ler_palavras serve para imprimir a lista com as palavras que se encontram num .txt
- a função analisarlinhas imprime o número da linha onde a palavra se encontra
- a função encontra_ocorrencias pega num ficheiro .txt e utiliza essas palavras para verificar onde se encontram no outro ficheiro

```
def analisarPalavras(nomeficheiro,string):
    with open(nomeficheiro,'r') as f:
        quantas = 0
        for linha in f:
            if string in linha:
                quantas = quantas + 1
        return quantas
    
def ler_palavras(nomeficheiro):
    with open(nomeficheiro,'r') as f:
        listaFinal = []
        listaIndividual = [linha.split() for linha in f]
        listaJunta = sum(listaIndividual,[])
        for i in listaJunta:
            if i not in listaFinal:
                listaFinal.append(i)
        return listaFinal

def analisarLinhas(nomeficheiro,palavra):
    linhaNumero = 0
    listaResultado = []
    with open(nomeficheiro,'r') as f:
        for linha in f:
            linhaNumero = linhaNumero + 1
            if palavra in linha:
                listaResultado.append(linhaNumero)
    return listaResultado


def encontra_ocorrencias(nomeficheiro1,nomeficheiro2):
    with open (nomeficheiro1,'r') as textoAnalisar, open(nomeficheiro2,'r') as palavrasInteresse:
        palavrasLidas = ler_palavras(nomeficheiro2)
        dicionario = {}
        for i in range(len(palavrasLidas)):
            palavraImprimir = (palavrasLidas[i])
            palavraLinha = (analisarPalavras(nomeficheiro1,palavraImprimir))
            numeroLinhas = (analisarLinhas(nomeficheiro1,palavraImprimir))
            dicionario.update({palavraImprimir: (palavraLinha,numeroLinhas)})
        return dicionario
```

Answer (score -1):

Partindo do princípio que as palavras no arquivo de texto a ser analisado serão separadas por espaços, qualquer outro pontuador deve ser incluído junto as palavras e a pesquisa será insensível ao caixa das letras, a abordagem usada na pergunta não é adequada ao problema proposto, pois a cada busca de informações sobre o arquivo é preciso reabri-lo e computar os dados. O que parece ser bem ineficiente e me levou a descartar o código original aproveitando apenas os requisitos.

Uma melhor abordagem seria abrir uma única vez o arquivo e obter numa única passagem todos os dados que precisa para trabalhar já estruturados, tabulados em [dicionários](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) aninhados e prontos para serem consultados. Segundo a estrutura:

```
<dicionário_externo> ::= {
  palavra 1 : dicionário_interno,
  palavra 2 : dicionário_interno,
          .
          .
          .
  palavra N : dicionário_interno
}

<dicionário_interno> ::= {
                      linha 1: colunas 
                      linha 2: colunas 
                            .
                            .
                            .
                      linha N: colunas 
                     }

 <colunas> ::= [coluna 1, coluna 2,.....,coluna N]
```

Onde:

- `palavra 1...palavra N` são as chaves do dicionário externo que por sua vez são a transcrição literal de cada palavra encontrada no arquivo texto.
- cada chave `palavra 1...palavra N` é atribuído um valor que também é um dicionário o dicionário_interno.
- `linha 1...linha N` são as chaves do dicionário interno que por sua vez são a transcrição literal do número da linha onde a palavra foi encontrada.
- cada chave `linha 1...linha N` é atribuído um valor que é uma lista onde `coluna 1,...,coluna N` são os números das colunas dentro da linha onde a palavra foi encontrada.

O programa define uma função `tabulartexto(arquivo)` que aceita o nome dum arquivo como entrada e executa os seguintes passos:

- Arbre *arquivo*.
- Lê *arquivo* para um string na memória.
- Fecha o *arquivo*.
- Quebra a string em linhas com o auxilio da função [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).
- Para cada linha a quebra em correspondências de palavras, envolvidas pelo objeto [`Match`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#match-objects), com o auxilio da função [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.finditer).
- Para cada correspondência é tabulado seus respectivos dados de interesse.

Então

```
import re

#Extrai uma tabela de informações de arquivo texto.
def tabulartexto(arquivo):
  tab = {}                                       #Tabela onde serão montados os dados.

  #Abre, lê o arquivo e salva seu conteúdo na memória dinâmica.
  with open(arquivo,'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

  #Quebra o arquivo em linhas e as enumera...
  for le in enumerate(s.lower().splitlines(True), 1):
    linha = le[0]                                 #...o numero da linha atual(facilitar a leitura).
    #...quebra a linha atual em correspondências de palavras e para cada uma delas...
    for m in re.finditer(r'(\S+)', le[1]):
      palavra = m.group(0)                        #...pega o texto da palavra.
      coluna = m.start(0) + 1                     #...pega a posição da coluna onde a palavra se inicia dentro de sua linha.
      #...verifica se a palavra já foi catalogada... 
      if palavra in tab:
        #...verifica se a linha contendo a palavra já foi catalogada...
        if linha in tab[palavra]:
          tab[palavra][linha].append(coluna)       #...adiciona a linha a posição da coluna onde a palavra se inicia.
        else:
          tab[palavra][linha] = [coluna]           #...cataloga a linha e a inicializa com o valor coluna onde a palavra se inicia.
      else:
        tab[palavra] = {linha : [coluna]}          #...cataloga a palavra e inicializa  linha com o valor coluna onde a palavra se inicia.
  return tab                                       #Retorna os dados tabulados.

#Conta quantas vezes a palavra aparece.
def analisarPalavras(palavra, tabela):
  p = palavra.lower()   
  return sum(map(len, tabela[p].values())) if p in tabela else 0;

#Retorna lista com as palavras que se encontram num arquivo.
def lerPalavras(tabela):
  return sorted(tabela.keys())

#Quantidade de ocorrências e os números das linhas da palavra.
def analisarLinhas(palavra, tabela):
  p = palavra.lower()   
  if p not in tabela:
    return None
  return [(len(tabela[p][l]), l) for l in tabela[p]]

#Cruzamento das ocorrências das palavras em dois arquivos.
def encontra_ocorrencias(tabela1, tabela2):
  return tabela1.keys() & tabela2.keys()
```

<sup>Veja esse exemplo em uso no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/TabulandoPalavras#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Poderia explicar o por que do voto negativo para que possa melhorar a resposta?